Recurring job is executing multiple times concurrently
I have a C# Worker that uses HangFire, here is the program.cs setup:
 var sqliteOptions = new SQLiteStorageOptions();
    builder.Services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
    .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
    .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
    .UseFilter(new DisableConcurrentExecutionAttribute(300))
    .UseSQLiteStorage($"Filename={hangfireDbPath};" , sqliteOptions));

  builder.Services.AddHangfireServer(options =>
  {
      options.WorkerCount = 1; // Limit to one worker
  });

Then in the Worker.cs I have this:
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    _fileMonitor.StartMonitoring();

    _logger.LogInformation("Backup service is starting.");

    // Start the Hangfire server
    using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
    {
        _backupService.ScheduleInitialJobs();

        _logger.LogInformation("Backup service has scheduled all initial backup jobs.");

        await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, stoppingToken);
    }


}

And my BackupService has this:
public void ScheduleInitialJobs()
{
    var backupPlans = _backupPlanService.GetAllBackupPlans();

    foreach (var plan in backupPlans)
    {
        if (plan.IsEnabled)
        {
            var cronExpression = GetCronExpression(plan);
            var options = new RecurringJobOptions
            {
                TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local
            };
            try
            {
                _recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate(
               plan.Name,
               () => ExecuteBackupAsync(plan, CancellationToken.None),
               cronExpression,
               options);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            
        }
    }
}

And this is my ExecuteBackupAsync method:
 [MaximumConcurrentExecutions(1)]
 public async Task ExecuteBackupAsync(BackupPlan plan, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
    ...
 }

I checked the Logs file and I can see this:
2024-05-15 23:05:09.297 -06:00 [DBG] 1 recurring job(s) processed by scheduler.
2024-05-15 23:05:09.302 -06:00 [DBG] 1 recurring job(s) processed by scheduler.
2024-05-15 23:05:24.113 -06:00 [DBG] Server ava:90924:57316309 heartbeat successfully sent
2024-05-15 23:05:24.165 -06:00 [INF] Executing backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.171 -06:00 [INF] Completed backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.378 -06:00 [DBG] Server ava:90924:0204f2f5 heartbeat successfully sent
2024-05-15 23:05:24.381 -06:00 [INF] Executing backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.382 -06:00 [INF] Completed backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.386 -06:00 [INF] Executing backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.387 -06:00 [INF] Completed backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.400 -06:00 [INF] Executing backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.401 -06:00 [INF] Completed backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.403 -06:00 [INF] Executing backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.404 -06:00 [INF] Completed backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.419 -06:00 [INF] Executing backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.420 -06:00 [INF] Completed backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.587 -06:00 [INF] Executing backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.588 -06:00 [INF] Completed backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.590 -06:00 [INF] Executing backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.591 -06:00 [INF] Completed backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.594 -06:00 [INF] Executing backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.595 -06:00 [INF] Completed backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.601 -06:00 [INF] Executing backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:24.602 -06:00 [INF] Completed backup for plan: Plan01
2024-05-15 23:05:54.125 -06:00 [DBG] Server ava:90924:57316309 heartbeat successfully sent
2024-05-15 23:05:54.387 -06:00 [DBG] Server ava:90924:0204f2f5 heartbeat successfully sent

This is killing me since I can confirm that only one time the RecurringJob is being added and I can check that in the HangFire db.
Help please!

Some thoughts:

Immediate thought is to add logging into that catch block in case it's failing
Whilst the log says it's completed successfully, has it really?  2 milliseconds seems very short for a backup (unless your job is just an empty method atm)
Failing the above: Is ExecuteBackupAsync getting "stuck" on the last plan in the list (Plan01) and in reality is executing N times for the loop against the same plan?  As the ExecuteBackupAsync is inside the delegate it's not executed at the time of the loop execution?


Good points I will check today all that and reply here. Appreciate it
